# UIActionSheet for deleting a UITableView cell on cancel keeps showing pressed Delete button

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When deleting a row in a table view, I want to show an action sheet asking for confirmation in certain situations. When the action sheet is answered with "Yes" (the destructive action), I delete the table row and everything is fine. But when Cancel is pressed, I still see the Delete button in a pressed state.

What I do in `tableView:commitEditingStyle` when deleting is this:

```
BlockBasedActionSheet *askSheet =
    [[BlockBasedActionSheet alloc] 
          initWithTitle:@"Delete entry?"
      cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, delete child also records"
           cancelAction:^{
               UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
               if (cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
                   cell.editing = NO;
                   cell.editingAccessoryView = nil;
                   cell.editing = YES;
               }
           }
  destructiveAction:deleteBlock];
[askSheet showInView:self.view];
[askSheet release];
```

What's also strange is that the cell's property `showingDeleteConfirmation` is `NO`, although the Delete button is still visible.

I am using a self-made block-based action sheet implementation. Maybe there lies the error, although I seem to get the correct cell in the cancel block.

So, how can I reset the Delete button state back to "unpressed" and remove it, and turn the round delete button back to horizontal, like it happens when I tap somewhere on the screen?

Helper class `BlockBasedActionSheet.h`:

```
@interface BlockBasedActionSheet : UIActionSheet<UIActionSheetDelegate> {
}

@property (copy) void (^cancelBlock)();
@property (copy) void (^destructiveBlock)();

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock destructiveAction:(void (^)())destructiveBlock;

@end
```

Implementation file `BlockBasedActionSheet.m`:

```
#import "BlockBasedActionSheet.h"

@implementation BlockBasedActionSheet
@synthesize cancelBlock = _cancelBlock, destructiveBlock = _destructiveBlock;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock destructiveAction:(void (^)())destructiveBlock
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles: nil];
    if (self) {
        _cancelBlock = Block_copy(cancelBlock);
        _destructiveBlock = Block_copy(destructiveBlock);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSAssert(actionSheet == self, @"Wrong Action Sheet passed");
    if (buttonIndex == [self cancelButtonIndex]) {
        if (self.cancelBlock) {
            self.cancelBlock();
        }
    } else {
        if (self.destructiveBlock) {
            self.destructiveBlock();
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it works by replacing the first code snippet with this

```
BlockBasedActionSheet *askSheet =
    [[BlockBasedActionSheet alloc] 
          initWithTitle:@"Delete entry?"
      cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, delete also child records"
           cancelAction:^{
           // this resets the delete button
           [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           }
  destructiveAction:deleteBlock];
[askSheet showInView:self.view];
[askSheet release];
```

Reloading the row does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `tableView:commitEditingStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a): *You should not call setEditing:animated: within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.*

My understanding is that this method is called once the delete button is beginning to disappear (hence `showingDeleteConfirmation` is `NO`) and so the stuff inside your if statement inside your block won't be called. If you set a breakpoint in there, am I right?

In any case, you might want to do as the documentation says and just have the table go back into editing mode after a millisecond delay.

**edit/update**

Created a new Navigation based project in Xcode. Changed this code. Set the table to show 10 rows with each row displaying its indexpath as the text. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2180315/crazycell.zip if you want the whole thing. You'll need to swipe to delete, I didn't make a dedicated delete button.

Calling `setEditing` on the cell object does nothing, even if `performSelector...` is used (I don't know why). But you can call `setEditing` on the `tableView` which as far as I can tell does what you want it to do (brings it back to the horizontal delete icons, with no delete button).

If this doesn't solve your problem then I'm really not sure what else can be done :/

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    BlockBasedActionSheet *askSheet =
    [[BlockBasedActionSheet alloc] 
     initWithTitle:@"Delete entry?"
     cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
     destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, delete child also records"
     cancelAction:^{
         [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
     }
     destructiveAction:^{
         NSLog(@"Delete block called");
     }];
     [askSheet showInView:self.view];
     [askSheet release];  
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to say, that in the line where I check `showingDeleteConfirmation` it is already NO. So, I could as well delete this `if`-block. But I still want the Delete button to disappear. I don't know what exactly happens when I confirm, because then the row dissapears. Maybe that's what the API expects, and so no longer cares about the button and its state (it is still shown pressed)

Comment: Yep, so if you want the delete button to disappear, set a timer with an interval of a few milliseconds.

Comment: Well, after 0.1 seconds (using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`) `showingDeleteConfirmation` is still `NO`. And even executing the block without the `if` (toggling editing and setting the view to `nil`) has absolutely no effect.

Comment: BTW., the documentation refers to `UITableView`. I toggle the edit mode at the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Updated my answer. I couldn't find a way of toggling the edit mode of the individual `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the delete button still shows up. BTW., with your code you actually break the rule calling `setEditing:animated:`. But even putting this call into a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not help. And the Dropbox link does not work.

Comment: Try the link again (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2180315/crazycell.zip). When I run the code I don't see the delete button, it goes back to looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/uvATB.png after hitting the cancel button.

Comment: Ha! I got it. It works to reload the row (it's that easy). So having the cancelBlock:
`^ {
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}` the row is shown with the horizontal delete icon and no Delete button.

Comment: @Alex No, your example does not work. It works for swipe-to-delete, since there the Delete button is removed before the action sheet comes up. But when using the "-" Buttons, it does not work. As I mentioned in my last comment it does using `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`.