# Use Block Based Action Sheet

Tags: iphone, uitableview, objective-c-blocks, uiactionsheet

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285210/uiactionsheet-for-deleting-a-uitableview-cell-on-cancel-keeps-showing-pressed-de) as a bit of a blueprint for setting up a block based action sheet.  My actions for the action sheet are Cancel, Download, and Stream.  I changed the BlockBasedActionSheet.h to:

```
 @interface BlockBasedActionSheet : UIActionSheet<UIActionSheetDelegate> {
}
@property (copy) void (^cancelBlock)();
@property (copy) void (^downloadBlock)();
@property (copy) void (^streamBlock)();


- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle downloadButtonTitle:(NSString *)downloadButtonTitle streamButtonTitle:(NSString *)streamButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock downloadAction:(void (^)())downloadBlock streamAction:(void (^)())streamBlock;

@end
```

and the BlockBasedActionSheet.m to:

```
@implementation BlockBasedActionSheet
@synthesize cancelBlock = _cancelBlock, streamBlock = _streamBlock, downloadBlock = _downloadBlock;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle downloadButtonTitle:(NSString *)downloadButtonTitle streamButtonTitle:(NSString *)streamButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock downloadAction:(void (^)())downloadBlock streamAction:(void (^)())streamBlock
{
self = [super initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:downloadButtonTitle, streamButtonTitle, nil];
if (self) {
    _cancelBlock = Block_copy(cancelBlock);
    _downloadBlock = Block_copy(downloadBlock);
    _streamBlock = Block_copy(streamBlock);
}
return self;
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSAssert(actionSheet == self, @"Wrong Action Sheet passed");
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    if (self.cancelBlock) {
        self.cancelBlock();
    }
}
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    if (self.downloadBlock) {
        self.downloadBlock();
    }
}
if (buttonIndex == 2) {
    if (self.streamBlock) {
        self.streamBlock();
    }
}
}

@end
```

In my TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I put the following:

```
    BlockBasedActionSheet *askSheet =
    [[BlockBasedActionSheet alloc] 
     initWithTitle:@"What Do You Want To Do" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" downloadButtonTitle:@"Download" streamButtonTitle:@"Stream" cancelAction:^ {

 }downloadAction:^ {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 49, 160, 50);
     progress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     cell.contentView.tag = 100;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:progress];
     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleUrl];    
     self.nameit = entry.articleTitle;
     NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
     receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
     NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

 }streamAction:^ {
     if (_webViewController == nil) {
         self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
     }
     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     _webViewController.entry = entry;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
 }];
[askSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
[askSheet release];
```

The Action Sheet Presents from top to bottom:
Download
Stream
Cancel

When I press Download, the Cancel action performs;
Stream, the Download action performs;
Cancel, the Stream Action performs

What have I done wrong that it is getting out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if (buttonIndex == [self cancelButtonIndex]) {
    if (self.cancelBlock) {
        self.cancelBlock();
    }
}
if (buttonIndex == [self firstOtherButtonIndex]) {
    if (self.downloadBlock) {
        self.downloadBlock();
    }
}
if (buttonIndex == [self firstOtherButtonIndex] +1) {
    if (self.streamBlock) {
        self.streamBlock();
    }
}
```